# empty a dialog after its closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

This is the cancel button function of a jquery dialog.

Does it make sense to empty the dialog after its closed above all when I set Cache: to false? I have seen this sometimes in www.

What could be the scenario where  need this?

```
"Cancel": function() { 
  $(this).dialog("close");
  $(this).empty();
}
```

Comment: Some times you need to reuse the dialog div.......then in that case it can be useful. but you should empty it first then close/destroy it.

Comment: @PriyankPatel Why? Closing first makes more sense, otherwise the UI would be in an inconsistent state, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

The only use I see of `empty` in this case is to let the memory be reclaimed, for efficiency or for clearing sensitive data. I have no knowledge of other reasons behind this, if they exist at all. In particular, there are no side-effects I'm aware of of **not** emptying a dialog after closing it.

It should also be noted that [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) does not just delete the contents of the element (its `innerHTML`) but also all [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) associated with them (with the children elements, that is - it does not remove the data of the element itself).

Comment: if you start with dunno and continue with believe... sorry ;-)

Comment: hehe ok, rephrasing the answer a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. `$('#divid').html('');` in your code. but be sure. it will empty the all content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I would just destroy the dialog on close:

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
```

then when dialog is called again, if no element exists with that id, the dialog will create the div dynamically and open it.